# How can I read with fread the content of file?

Tags: c, file, fread

given the following text-file ("file_text);

```
example text
```

I'm trying to read the content of this file in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char* arr = malloc(64);
  FILE* f_fd = fopen("file_txt", "r");
  fread(arr, 1, 64, f_fd);
  printf("|%s|\n", arr);
  return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't print the really content of the file. I see for example: `|P?p|` or `|P^2|` ..
And I don't understand why I get it.

NOTES: 64 is the max size of this file.

Comment: What happens if you replace `malloc` with `calloc` to set the trailing `\0'`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri do you mean to `calloc(64,1)` ? if yes so I get `||` - empty string.

Comment: None of the 2 tests happen here. It works with both malloc (tho it is UB, because you are, indeed, missing the terminal 0. But that should print `example text` then, if not lucky enough to have 0 in your `arr`, some garbage, and, eventually, a seg fault). And with calloc.

Comment: Have you tested the return value of fopen and fread?

Comment: For the `\0` problem, I would rather than filling `arr` with 0, just add it: `nread=fread(arr, 1, 64, f_fd)` then `arr[nread]='\0'`. But then you need arr to be length 65, or to limit size of reading to 63. Because fread reads bytes, not strings. It doesn't bother for adding a 0, nor leaving a free place for it.

Comment: (Even with any other method, such as calloc, you have the same problem: you can't fread 64 bytes in a `char [64]` buffer, and have a terminal 0 safely: either the terminal 0 won't be there, or you risk an overflow while putting it, if string is exactly 64 chars long)

Comment: But well, that is a problem in your code, the missing `\0`, and also the missing place to have it even when string is 64 chars long. But I am pretty sure that is not the problem your are experiencing. That one is probably caused by a typo or some other silly error. Because your code works well (other than above mentioned errors). So, are you sure your file is there, with correct name, that there aren't two of them, that it contains what you think it contains, that it is readable, etc, etc.

Comment: you get here errno = 2 because file not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your file is "file_text", but you trying to open this file with:

```
fopen("file_txt", "r");
```

try to open it with `"file_text"` file name.